# Function to determine window in a rolling function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I want to apply a rolling mean over a column of numbers that come in 3-pairs where I only want 4 unique values to go into the mean.
Lets say my dataframe looks like:

```
     Group  Column to roll    
       1       9
       2       5
       2       5
       2       4
       2       4
       2       4
       2       3
       2       3
       2       3
       2       6
       2       6
       2       6
       2       8
```

Since I want 4 unique values to go into the mean but all values to be of equal weight and within the same group, my expected output (assuming I need 4 unique values) would be:

```
         Group    Output   
            1       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2       nan
            2     (6+3+4+5)/4
            2     (6+3+4+5)/4
            2     (6+3+4+5)/4
            2     (8+6+3+4)/4
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I edited my post, maybe you can help with that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df['Column to roll'].drop_duplicates().rolling(4).mean().reindex(df.index).ffill()
```

Output:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
8     4.50
9     4.50
10    4.50
11    5.25
Name: Column to roll, dtype: float64
```

#### Edit question changed

```
df_out = df.groupby('Group')['Column to roll']\
           .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().rolling(4).mean()).rename('Output')

df.set_index('Group',append=True).swaplevel(0,1)\
  .join(df_out, how='left').ffill().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       Column to roll  Output
Group                        
1                   9     NaN
2                   5     NaN
2                   5     NaN
2                   4     NaN
2                   4     NaN
2                   4     NaN
2                   3     NaN
2                   3     NaN
2                   3     NaN
2                   6    4.50
2                   6    4.50
2                   6    4.50
2                   8    5.25
```

Comment: Hallo Scott, 
It seems as if it almost does the trick. Only extra part is that I have a groupby object aswell. Let me try to update my df in the question to show you. Thank you so much so far

Comment: You not rolling by group, so you can just assign this result to a new column in the dataframe.  The reason I guess that you aren't rolling buy group because you still have the value 3 in the calculation for row 8, 9, and 10.

Comment: I want to roll by group :) I updated the desired output above.